# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at new Script (vm.js:88:7) ect

Tags: discord.js

I am programming a bot for Discord using Discord.js. ive tried diffrent situations but everytime i run the command:

```
client.on("message", async message => {

if(command === "ban") {
     if(!message.member.roles.some(r=>["Administrator"].includes(r.name)) )
return message.reply("Sorry, you don't have permissions to use this!");
let member = message.mentions.members.cache.first();
if(!member)
return message.reply("Please mention a valid member of this server");
if(!member.bannable)
return message.reply("I cannot ban this user! Do they have a higher role? Do I have ban permissions?");
let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
if(!reason) reason = "No reason provided";
await member.ban(reason)
.catch(error => message.reply(`Sorry ${message.author} I couldn't ban because of : ${error}`));
message.reply(`${member.user.tag} has been banned by ${message.author.tag} because: ${reason}`);
};`Sorry ${message.author} I couldn't ban because of : ${error}`));
message.reply(`${member.user.tag} has been banned by ${message.author.tag} because: ${reason}`);
};
```

i get this error:

```
    SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
at new Script (vm.js:88:7)
at createScript (vm.js:263:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:311:10)
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1057:15)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1120:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
at /home/runner/Kylah-10/index.js:17:17
```

can someone please help me out thank you!

Comment: If you were to use indenting, the problem might be more apparent,

Comment: Can you look at the `Sorry` text and see if it is out of place? the one on the third line from the bottom? ie. `};'Sorry ...` ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not closing your paranthesis (& you have a random string in your code). Please try the following:

```
client.on("message", async message =>
{

    if (command === "ban")
    {
        if (!message.member.roles.some(r => ["Administrator"].includes(r.name)))
            return message.reply("Sorry, you don't have permissions to use this!");
        let member = message.mentions.members.cache.first();
        if (!member)
            return message.reply("Please mention a valid member of this server");
        if (!member.bannable)
            return message.reply("I cannot ban this user! Do they have a higher role? Do I have ban permissions?");
        let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
        if (!reason) reason = "No reason provided";
        await member.ban(reason)
            .catch(error => message.reply(`Sorry ${message.author} I couldn't ban because of : ${error}`));
        message.reply(`${member.user.tag} has been banned by ${message.author.tag} because: ${reason}`);
    };
});
```